# Problems with containerdefinition in aws to work with secrets

Tags: terraform, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have a containerdefinition to populate tasks in a cluster, like this one, I'm trying just two things, first of all with a command I want to write a simple hello to my index.html:

```
[ {
"name": "cb-app",
"image": "${app_image}",
"cpu": ${fargate_cpu},
"memory": ${fargate_memory},
"networkMode": "awsvpc",
"command":[
  "bin/sh -c \"echo 'hola222' > /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html\""
],
"entryPoint": [
        "sh",
    "-c"
],
"logConfiguration": {
    "logDriver": "awslogs",
    "options": {
      "awslogs-group": "/ecs/cb-app",
      "awslogs-region": "${aws_region}",
      "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
    }
},
"secrets": [
  {
    "name": "USERNAME2_VALUE",
    "valueFrom": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:xxxxx:xxxxxxx:secret:USERNAME2_VALUE-ipilBA"
  }
],
"portMappings": [
  {
    "containerPort": 80,
    "hostPort": 80
  },
  {
    "containerPort": 22,
    "hostPort": 22
   }
  ]
 }
]
```

I have an ecr with a simple nginx-alpine image. If I work without the entryPoint and command, it works fine and it shows the first page of the webserver but when I write the entryPoing and command. It doesn't work and I don't know why. I am using fargate. Could you help me?. Thanks a lot.
When I write the command and entryPoint all task stop and I have an exitCode 0.

This is what I have and I don't have any kind of log

[image]

As well, I get STOPPED (Essential container in task exited) on the tasks which were stopped

Comment: When you say doesn't work do you get an error? If so you should edit your question to include the error.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR, just I have what I have added on the image.

Comment: How are you creating your task via console or via CLI/API? 
Maybe try using your command like:  "command":["echo hola222 > /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html"],

Comment: @Haran, I am using Terraform

Comment: As @Haran says, it doesn't work too

Comment: If it's the same error, then try running outside of Fargate. Verify whether you are able to run the container with overriding the entrypoint. `docker run --entrypoint "/bin/sh" <image> cmd"

Comment: @Haram, I receive a /bin/sh can't open ls. No such file or directory. And if I do an inspect I have a nging -g daemon off on cmd

Comment: Could you send a command you are running? If you are getting an error like "no such file or directory" with --ENTRYPOINT with "docker run" one of the possibilities of the cause could be the way CMD arguments are passed.
Refer https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#entrypoint-default-command-to-execute-at-runtime

Comment: I have modify the Dockerfile from the image and I have change the Entrypoint there, and running it on the command line, I have what you say. Thanks